# Ajax call in for loop returns same value only once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know it has been asked multiple times but I cant seem to figure the `closure` stuff out, atleast I can't seem to apply it to my own code.

here I create a for loop based on the `.choice` class.

```
   <label class="choice" data-id="1"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="een">een</label>
   <label class="choice" data-id="2"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="twee">twee</label>
   <label class="choice" data-id="3"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="drie">drie</label>
   <label class="choice" data-id="4"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="vier">vier</label>

$(document).ready(function(){
for (var i = $('.choice').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var element = $('.choice')[i];
    var choiceID = $(element).data('id');
    var value = $(element).find('input').val();

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'api.php',
        data: {
            choiceID: choiceID, 
            value: value
        },
        success: function(res) {

            if(value == JSON.parse(res).value) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(res).value);
                console.log(JSON.parse(res).count);
                if(JSON.parse(res).count > 0){
                    $(element).addClass('full');
                }
            } else {
                // console.log("FAILED " + JSON.parse(res).value);
                // console.log("FAILED " + JSON.parse(res).count);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

});

Then on the `api.php` file I call multiple query's

```
$choiceID = $_POST["choiceID"];
$value = $_POST["value"];
$kolom = "choice_" . $choiceID;

$counter = 0;
$array = [];

$query = "SELECT choice_1 FROM resultaten WHERE choice_1 = '".$value."'";
$getCount = $db->query($query);
$getCount->execute(array("value"=>$value));
$results = $getCount->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`more queries and for loops` 
ajax succes callback
`echo json_encode(array("value" => $value, "count"=> $counter, "ID" => $choiceID));`

for the first `choice` class with a `data-id` of `1` it works and applies the class `full`

but when i console.log the `value` and `count` it returns `een 1`
and in the console
 `VM1982:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1` Probably something to do with the `data-id` of `1/2/3/4` etc. (I think it should all be `one`) but when I put them all to `1` it just works for the first one. Same as when I use `1/2/3/4` as `data-id`. Also it is kinda weird that it with some results returns  `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: choice_2 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\form\api.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />
{"value":"use your apple","count":2,"ID":"2"}` It says it has a `count` of 2 and in the ajax it says when `count` = above 0 it sould give the class `full` but it gives the `undefined index: choice_2` instead

> I think this causes the main problem

And when I `console.log` `value` inside of the `succes` function it returns `een` which is the `first` value of the `choice` classes.

while when I `console.log` the `value` below the `value` variable it returns all of the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `element`, `choiceID`, and `value` are all changing synchronously. By the time the AJAX response gets back, the values are different from when each request began.

This is probably the easiest change you code make

```
for (var i = $('.choice').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  (function() {
    var element = $('.choice')[i];
    var choiceID = $(element).data('id');
    var value = $(element).find('input').val();

    // rest of your loop code here...
  })();
}
```

Now, each time the loop runs, `element`, `choiceID`, and `value` will have their values properly bound to the closure.

---

You're not using the `i` iterator, otherwise it's common to see that passed into the Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).

```
for (var i = $('.choice').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  (function(i) {
    // your loop code here
  })(i);
}
```

---

Anyway, this is all just a symptom of bad code design in general. If you used functions to describe the separate operations of your code (instead of one giant blob inside a `for` loop), you would've never had this issue to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to change couple of things :

```
$choiceID = $_POST["choiceID"];
$value = $_POST["value"];
$kolom = "choice_" . $choiceID;

$counter = 0;
$array = [];

$query = "SELECT choice_1 FROM resultaten WHERE $kolom = '".$value."'";
$getCount = $db->query($query);
$getCount->execute(array("value"=>$value));
$results = $getCount->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($results ) {
    echo json_encode($results );
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

now in javascript, you should parse non zero response.